# Having trouble decoding JSON file in swift

Tags: json, swift, xcode, jsondecoder

I am trying to decode a JSON format from CalorieNinja API but it appears that the equals signs in their jsons are throwing my code off. Here is my code for decoding the JSON file:

```
 let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            
            //check errors
            if error == nil && data != nil {
                
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                do{
                    let result = try decoder.decode(Result.self, from: data!)
                    print(result)
                }catch{
                    print("there was an error")
                    print(error)
                }
                
            }
            
        }
```

Here are my structs:

```
struct FoodItem: Codable {
    var name: String?
    var calories: String?
}

struct Result: Codable {
    
    var items: [FoodItem]?
    
}
```

Here is the JSON format that gets returned from CalorieNinjas(this is just an example this is not the output of my code):

```
{
    items =     (
                {
            calories = "18.2";
            "carbohydrates_total_g" = "3.9";
            "cholesterol_mg" = 0;
            "fat_saturated_g" = 0;
            "fat_total_g" = "0.2";
            "fiber_g" = "1.2";
            name = tomato;
            "potassium_mg" = 23;
            "protein_g" = "0.9";
            "serving_size_g" = 100;
            "sodium_mg" = 4;
            "sugar_g" = "2.6";
        }
    );
}
```

And lastly here is the error if it helps at all:

```
typeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "items", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "calories", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found a number instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

Comment: The JSON you've posted here is not valid JSON. Is it actually what you're receiving, or have you printed an NSDictionary that is parsed from the JSON? If this is the actual bytes you're receiving, it's not JSON and Codable won't work. If it's not, you need to show the JSON that you really receive. According to your error, the actual bytes being parsed have a number for `calories`, but your output has a string, so I don't think this is what you're passing to the decoder.

Comment: @RobNapier Yah I think you are right. I feel super dumb I'm totally lost on how to solve this issue im sorry for my stupidity this is my first time working with an API. Im going to go back to the documentation like a good boy.

Comment: Tools like Paw (https://paw.cloud) or Postman (https://www.postman.com) can help you a lot here by showing you what the JSON really looks like. Helps avoid a lot of guessing. Quicktype (https://app.quicktype.io/?l=swift) can generally write all the code for you, as well.

Comment: To resolve your issue, you can just try to change                                <<<struct FoodItem: Codable {
    var name: String?
    var calories: String?
}>>>                                             to                                  <<<struct FoodItem: Codable {
    var name: String?
    var calories: Double? // or CGFloat? etc according to your needs
}>>>  In other words, change the type of calories field to Double?. Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check CalorieNinja API again. 
 I think the calories field should be Double? due to their document.[image]

Comment: Yes thank you I'm so sorry you just saved my day I was ready to throw my computer